# Local Broadcast Receiver Exception: android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

**NOTE:** Activity Flag with `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.android.servicerestart"));
        if(broadcastReceiver != null) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException E)
            {

            }
        }

        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Activity","In OnDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        if(broadcastReceiver != null) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException E)
            {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("Activity","In OnPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        registerReceiver();
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("Activity","In onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            registerReceiver();
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {

        }
    }
```

**registerReceiver();**

```
private void registerReceiver() {
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };

    try {
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("*******.receive.service.download"));
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {

    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
E/ActivityThread: Activity **********.activity.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver **********.activity.MainActivity$3@3318724 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity **********.activity.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver **********.activity.MainActivity$3@3318724 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1164)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:951)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1308)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1288)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1282)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:586)
    at **********.activity.MainActivity.registerReceiver(MainActivity.java:203)
    at **********.activity.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:156)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1255)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2712)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2810)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1530)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6256)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:793)
```

Comment: Why have you registered and unregistered the receiver twice?  Just register and unregister it in onResume() and onPause()

Comment: Registering and unregistering receivers twice? Why, why? `onPause() -> onStop()`,  this is the lifecycle. Now, `onPause()` has already unregistered your receiver, and comes the latter `onStop()` call, which tries to unregister previously unregistered receiver and that's why you're getting this exception. I suggest you either register-unregister in resume-pause or start-stop lifecylce method pair--not both.

Comment: this happens because i am registering receiver and unregistered receiver twice ?

Comment: For one thing that I clearly see is, you should set `broadcastReceiver = null`, after every invocation to `unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);`

Comment: @ZeekHuge ok i will try

Comment: Also, make sure you use print at least something in the exception-handlers, so you know that its working (and not producing an exception instead).

Comment: @ZeekHuge thanks for your response sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Lifecycle issue

Both `start` and `resume` register a receiver - but there is no check whether a receiver already exists (so you register two separate receivers)

This means on `pause` and `destroy` methods can only see the second one and the first is leaked.

The best fix is to remove the start/destroy blocks. Otherwise you may wrap your `new BroadcastReceiver` block in `if (broadcastReceiver == null)`

Comment: sorry sir miss understand activity lifecycle